# Exporting variables for use in other modules in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need some pointers as a newcomer to all things Node and JS.

This is undoubtedly explained in more depth elsewhere but I just need to get something working fast to help foster my understanding.

I have a main entry point to my small Node app that generates new users by calling service end points to an API.

I have attempted to randomize the user data using a node library to make it more realistic and....random!

**personBuilder.js**

```
const { build, fake, oneOf } = require("test-data-bot");

const personBuilder = build("User").fields({
  firstname: fake((f) => f.name.firstname()),
  lastname: fake((f) => f.name.lastname()),
  dob: oneOf(
    "1969-03-24",
    "1983-07-05",
    "1956-12-23",
    "1990-11-13",
    "1974-10-08",
    "1987-01-31"
  ),
  addressone: fake((f) => f.address.streetName()),
  addresstwo: fake((f) => f.address.streetAddress()),
  postcode: oneOf("M5 2TS", "SA2 2AE", "LE3 4AJ", "TW8 1AX", "PE3 1AN"),
});

const newPerson = personBuilder();
console.log(newPerson);

module.exports = [
  {
    firstName: newPerson.firstname,
    lastName: newPerson.lastname,
    dob: newPerson.dob,
    address: {
      addressLine1: newPerson.addressone,
      addressLine2: newPerson.addresstwo,
      postcode: newPerson.postcode,
    },
  },
];
```

I want to require this in a separate file in which I set global data in Json format for use in a Newman(Postman) collection:

**generateNewUsers.js**

```
const personData = require("./support/personBuilder");
const newman = require("newman");

const setGlobals = (newPerson) => {
  return {
    id: "5bfde907-2a1e-8c5a-2246-4aff74b74236",
    name: "test-env",
    values: [
      {
        key: "firstName",
        value: newPerson.firstname,
        type: "text",
        enabled: true,
      },// more data values...
```

My issue is that although the newPerson is being successfully created with all values, the values are not being set in setGlobals (they are null as far as I can tell in debugging).

Inevitably, this is a simple issue around fundamental misunderstanding of how data is exported / imported (required).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you can't export an array using `modules.exports`. please remove the square brackets and return the object itself.

Comment: reading this:: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

`modules.exports` only supports an object to be returned.

```js
module.exports =
  {
    firstName: newPerson.firstname,
    lastName: newPerson.lastname,
    dob: newPerson.dob,
    address: {
      addressLine1: newPerson.addressone,
      addressLine2: newPerson.addresstwo,
      postcode: newPerson.postcode,
    },
  };
```

this should help you.
or if you want to export multiple persons you could use

```js
module.exports = {
    persons: [
      {
        firstName: newPerson.firstname,
        lastName: newPerson.lastname,
        dob: newPerson.dob,
        address: {
          addressLine1: newPerson.addressone,
          addressLine2: newPerson.addresstwo,
          postcode: newPerson.postcode,
        },
      },
    ]
};
```

and to retrive the persons you can use the destruct method.

```js
const {persons} = require("./support/personBuilder");
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Anees is good but I want to mention that if you returning some data, you can use a `bean with setters and getters methods` instead and `expose/export the methods`!